# Help on output formatting

Tags: output-formatting

Again, I am writing homework sheets. I have tried

```
 a = "(portionOfCircle)";
 SectorArea =  a * Pi * r^2 
 SectorArea =  a * Pi * r^2 // TeXForm
 With[{a = "portionOfCircle"}, Defer[a * Pi * r^2 // TeXForm]]
```

I would like the output to be in LaTeX form such as  $$\text{(portion  of circle)}\cdot \pi r^2$$ instead my code will output  $$\pi \text{(portion  of circle)}\cdot  r^2$$

Also, I would like

```
 a = RandomChoice[{Pi/6, Pi/4, 5 Pi/4}]/(2 Pi)
 SectorArea = a*Pi*r^2
 SectorArea = a*Pi*r^2 // TeXForm
 With[{a = a}, Defer[a*Pi*r^2]]
```

to output $$\frac{\pi/4}{2\pi}\cdot \pi r^2$$ instead, it simplifies the fraction hiding the concept i'm trying to emphasize.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just to clarify my comment earlier, here is a solution for the second part of the question (no need to duplicate an answer to the first part) that I think serves the intended purpose:

```
Row[{Row[{RandomChoice[{Pi/6, Pi/4, 5 Pi/4}]}]/HoldForm[2 Pi], 
   " \[Times] ", HoldForm[Pi*r^2]}] // TraditionalForm
```

[image: output]

Here I added the `\[Times]` symbol just to show that you can add arbitrary decorations by means of `Row`, to make the output look even clearer.

Comment: very nice! this is exactly what I was looking for ... thank all of u for your help much appreciated!

Comment: Yes, this is nice. +1.

Answer (score 3):

What you want to use (for the first part) is `HoldForm`.

i.e.

```
TeXForm@With[{a = "portionOfCircle"}, HoldForm[a*Pi*r^2]]
```

which returns

```
\text{portionOfCircle} \pi  r^2
```

as desired.

The problem with using `Defer` is that it simply holds until the expression evaluated. In your example, when the output of `Defer` is fed to `TeXForm` it gets evaluated prior to formatting it for TeX output. `HoldForm` will preserve the form under all future manipulations until you explicitly call `ReleaseForm`.

Comment: thank you @covopsdaf2, i think I need to add HoldForm to my bag of tools.. I understand it thank you, does exactly what I needed.

Comment: `HoldForm` is the way I would go, too (+1). Maybe also combined with `Row` when you mix strings and numbers.

Comment: @Jens `HoldForm` does not address the second part of the question, which (to me at least) was the main one.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin It's so easy to do this with `Row` and `HoldForm`, I just don't think one should even start the way the OP did...

Comment: @Jens The second part of the question was not about positioning, and I don't see how you solve that problem with `Row` and `HoldForm`. But, whatever, no big deal anyway.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin I added an answer with the code I had in mind.