# Output short denominator as pre-factor

Tags: output-formatting, style

How can I make the output print like the input, with the short denominator written as a factor in front of the long expression?

[image]

I was messing with styles earlier today to do something else, and at one point it started printing like that, so I know it can be done, but then it reverted back.

Comment: `Defer[1/f] g`.

Comment: @Coolwater Could you elaborate more on your comment, please?

Comment: For your convenience, you could add your original code. In that way you will help community help you. It's easier copying code instead of writing down from scratch.

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21502/help-on-output-formatting

Comment: @MichaelE2 Only checked this Q out today - your deleted answer looks very useful! It could be added to $POST to automate it. And maybe a condition on the ratio of `LeafCount`s could be added.

Comment: @Jens Thanks for letting me know.  I've undeleted it.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if all you want is formatted output.  With [`Interpretation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Interpretation.html) you get output you can copy.

```
Clear[fracform]
fracform[e_] /; Denominator[e] =!= 1 := 
  Interpretation[
   DisplayForm@ RowBox[{ToBoxes[1/Denominator[e]], " ", ToBoxes[Numerator[e]]}], 
   e];
fracform[e_] := e;

fracform[a/b]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: All I want is formatted output, so that when I print my Mathematica sheet to pdf and include it in my latex document it looks more readable.

Comment: So it works, then?  (One could also replace `Interpretation[..]` by its first argument.)